# Computer went to sleep during upgrade to 13.04, I get a blinking start up screen after restart

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, 13.04

I updated from 12.04 to 13.04, and in the middle of running the upgrade, I accidentally put the computer to sleep (HP mini 2011), thinking all was lost I stupidly restarted the computer. Now there is nothing expect a repeating blinking bit of the start up procedure.

I am really new at this so I can't be much more specific. I don’t have anything on a USB and this computer has no CD.

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like a graphic card driver issue, but if you have no cd and no usb then you're pretty much stuck I'm afraid... the installation simply didn't complete.

Answer (score 3):

I would try to manually complete the update. Restart your computer and hold the Shift key down. You should see a simple menu (the GRUB menu). Select the rescue mode option (it's likely to be the second item on the list) and hit Enter.

If the rescue mode boots correctly, you should be represented with a new menu. Start by selecting the root with network option.

Depending on how badly the system update was interrupted, running the following command may finish the update:

```
apt-get dist-upgrade
```

If that commands says that there are no packages to be installed (or complains about broken packages), use these commands one after an other:

```
apt-get -f install
dpkg --configure -a
```

It is not necessary to run the second command if the first command finishes without any error messages.